# How do I sum a column based on multiple sets of OR criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with a target sum column (ColA) and three columns to filter based on criteria.  I've been using SUMIFS to calculate the sum of ColA based on the criteria columns Cols B through D however I notice I'm not doing this correctly.
One thing to note is that the criteria columns have varying amounts of criteria each (e.g. column B has more OR conditions than C)

My current formula is:

```
SUM(SUMIFS(table[ColA], table[colB], {"val1", "val2", "val3"}, table[colC], {"val1", "val2"}, table[colD], {"val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"}))
```

The result of this formula is incorrect after manually checking the sum in the underlying table.  Any advice on how to sum a column based on a set of multiple OR values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do a SUMPRODUCT which will get long:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(table[ColA]*
  ((table[colB]="val1")+(table[colB]="val2")+(table[colB]="val3")>0)*
  ((table[colC]="val1")+(table[colC]="val2")>0)*
  ((table[colD]="val1")+(table[colD]="val2")+(table[colD]="val3")+(table[colD]="val4")>0))
```

To understand, the `*` is the equivalent to `AND`, the `+` is equivalent to `OR`

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your table is called Table1, starts in A1 with headers, and is 4 columns wide. In a cell somewhere to the right, let's say G2, you could enter this formula:

```
=AND(OR(B2={"val1","val2","val3"}),OR(C2={"val1","val2"}),OR(D2={"val1","val2","val3","val4"}))
```

leaving G1 blank, then your sum formula is just:

```
=DSUM(Table1[#All],1,G1:G2)
```

You could also break the criteria formula up into three cells, one for each column, using:

```
=OR(B2={"val1","val2","val3"})
=OR(C2={"val1","val2"})
=OR(D2={"val1","val2","val3","val4"})
```

in G2:I2 (either leave G1:I1 blank, or give them labels that do **not** match any of your table headers), then use:

```
=DSUM(Table1[#All],1,G1:I2)
```

Comment: So it does have the same restriction.  It cannot be done without helper columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner It's a helper **cell**, not a column. :) All the D-functions require a criteria *range*.

Comment: Ahh, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `MATCH()` nested in `SUMPRODUCT()`:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B6,{"Val1","Val2","Val3"},0)+MATCH(C2:C6,{"Val1","Val2"},0)+MATCH(D2:D6,{"Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4"},0))*A2:A6)
```